# Jquery menu without using data-id tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I have created a really nice jQuery menu, which loads different content as you select each of the tabs at the top.

However, I can no longer use the 'data-id' tags which are used within the code, as this apparently interfers with HTML purifier.  I know there are numerous arguments against this subject, and you should be allowed to enable certain tags, but ultimately, I am unable to use these tags.

I would therefore appreciate some input on how I can restructure this menu, whilst still keeping its look intact, but not using data-id tags.

I also notice that when you run this code in jsfiddle, it quickly loads the content of all 4 menu items before displaying just the content for menu item 1 (i.e, it brings up a list - menu content 1, menu item content 2, menu item content 3 and menu item content 4).

Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/m83ntmfz/

HTML

```
<div>
   <ul id="listingmenu">
   <li class="current"><a href="#!" data-id="div1">MENU ITEM 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#!" data-id="div2">MENU ITEM 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#!" data-id="div3">MENU ITEM 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#!" data-id="div4">MENU ITEM 4</a></li>
   </ul><br><br>
   <div class="pbox" id="div1">content for menu item 1</div>
   <div class="pbox" id="div2">content for menu item 2</div>
   <div class="pbox" id="div3">content for menu item 3</div>
   <div class="pbox" id="div4">content for menu item 4</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
ul#listingmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

    ul#listingmenu li {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #272e3b;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul#listingmenu .current {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #fe8f25;
    }

    ul#listingmenu li:hover {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #fe8f25;
    }

    ul#listingmenu li a {
        padding: 2px 2px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 12px Avenir, Arial, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        color: #272e3b;
    }

        ul#listingmenu li a:hover {
            color: #fe8f25;
            border: none;
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function () {
              $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Comment: add $('.pbox').toggle(); below $(document).ready(function () { and it will not load all the sub menus on load event

Comment: You can use element indexes if you do not want to use data-ids. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717071/jquery-menu-without-using-data-id-tags/32717469#32717469) with working demo

Answer (score 0):

You could use the href attribute:

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul id="listingmenu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#div1">MENU ITEM 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2">MENU ITEM 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div3">MENU ITEM 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div4">MENU ITEM 4</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
<div class="pbox" id="div1">content for menu item 1</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">content for menu item 2</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">content for menu item 3</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">content for menu item 4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var lastItem = null;
    $('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        newItem = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
        if (newItem != lastItem) {
            $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
            // fade out all open subcontents
            $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
            // fade in new selected subcontent
            $('#' + newItem).show(600);
            lastItem = newItem;
        }
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

JSFIddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/m83ntmfz/3/

Comment: thats great, thanks.  When the content loads in one of the sections, for example menu 1, I would like to prevent it from re-loading if you click the same menu item again, as it is already loaded.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Laruiss. There does seem to be an issue if you add too much content within each section, or view on a smaller device, in which case it opens the content in the middle of the section, and you have to scroll back up the page to begin reading.  Is this something that can be resolved within the javascript?

Comment: to give a bit more detail, if I add in an image for example, it scrolls to the bottom of the page, and I then have to go back to the top to view the content?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to add event.preventDefault() for that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in fiddle now?  Are you able to resend?

Comment: For me it is working, yes. What do you mean by "resend" ?

Comment: the jsfiddle doesn't work, so i thought i may be opening an incorrect file/version

Answer (score 0):

## **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/m83ntmfz/2/)**

You can use a strategy as like as in twitter bootstrap tabs. I mean you can use element index if you do not want to use data-ids. In this case, links and related contends must be in same order as in your case. You can easily understand when you look at following code.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul id="listingmenu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#!">MENU ITEM 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">MENU ITEM 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">MENU ITEM 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">MENU ITEM 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="pbox">content for menu item 1</div>
    <div class="pbox">content for menu item 2</div>
    <div class="pbox">content for menu item 3</div>
    <div class="pbox">content for menu item 4</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#listingmenu li').on('click', function() {
            var currentIndex = $(this).index();
            $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
            // fade out all open subcontents
            $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
            // fade in new selected subcontent
    
    
            $('.pbox:eq(' + currentIndex + ')').show(600);
        })
        $('#listingmenu li').first().click();
    });
```